# Symfony2: how to login only by password

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony2.3 I have a user entity (I use doctrine) where the username is not unique, but the password is. How do I implement a login system. As far as I can see, Symfony2 uses loadUserByUsername() and I would like a loadUserByPassword().

Any ideas to how I do it. I have tried a custom user provider, and a entity provider, but I can't find where I can get the users password and search the database.

Thanks for your help.

### Regards Niels

Edit:

I will try to explain the scenario in more detail. 
I have some administrators that login using FosUserBundle in the normal FosUser way. These administrators can create some surveys, and they can create some respondents with username and password to answer the survey. The administrator have access to the passwords, so he can give them to the respondent either by mail or a handout ( I can't rely on all respondent have email ).

The administrator has to have access to the passwords so they are saved as plaintext in the database. It is even possible for the administrator to give the survey as a print on paper to the respondent, and enter the answers for the respondent.

The idea of the survey is that the administrator can ask the user to answer the survey again, so they can talk about the change in answers over a period of time. It is a sort of monitoring the progress.

The idea that @Pierre suggested with some "invitation codes" is some thing I haven't thought about. I will look into that and see if I can use it. The important thing is to have a system where the administrator can be sure that he can give a respondent access to the survey (with login information), more than one time, so they together can compare the difference in the answers.

@andrzej-osmialowski ask what I mean with a custom user class. I have created an entity that I use to save all the respondents to the database (see code below). In my security.yml I have 2 providers one for the respondents using the infoClient class, and one for the administrators(FosUserBundle).

I hope you can give me some ideas.

```
class infoClient implements AdvancedUserInterface, Serializable, EquatableInterface
{
/** 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"registration"},message = "Respondenten skal have et fornavn")
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $firstName;

/** 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $lastName;

/**
 * @var string $email
 * @Assert\Email()
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255,  nullable=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $isActive = true;

/** 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $salt;

/** 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false, unique = true)
 */
private $plainPassword;

/**
 * @var string $username
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"registration"},message = "Respondenten skal have et brugernavn")
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $username;

/** 
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $borndate;

/** 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $group_identity;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array");
 */
private $roles = array();

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 */
private $created;

/** 
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 */
private $updated;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Dhsf\AnswerBundle\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="infoClient",cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $answers;

div. getters and setters

}
```

Comment: I think it's a not good idea

Comment: Its a terrible idea.  What if more than one person has the same password?

Comment: The passwords is validated as unique, so what I have is not unique usernames but unique passwords. It is for at small survey system where some administrators, validated though FosUserBundle, create the  respondents with unique passwords. The respondents don't necessarily have an email so it is important the administrator can administer the passwords.

Comment: @nipri you should not assume that passwords would be unique unless you generate them on your own. From the other hand, how do you recognize a responder?

Comment: The password I do generate my self, and the administrators can't create a respondent unless the password is unique. The respondent is recognized by the combination of username and password. I use a custom user class

Comment: To validate the passwords as unique, do you store them as plaintext? If so, you can simply switch usernames and passwords, it's a security fiasco anyway. However, if you want something that is secure and user friendly, you should think about giving out "invitation codes" that can be entered on the site and be used to create a regular account that meets standard security requirements.

Comment: @nipri - what do you mean by saying `custom user class`? An entity? User provider? If you want to get rid of the password, do you want to get rid of the user account? I think I can't understand your point of view unfortunately. Please, edit your question and describe it a bit more.